# Insert statement failing for influxDB

Tags: insert, influxdb

I am using line protocol to write simple data as shown below into Influx DB.

```
interface1,KEY=bytes_allocated,fieldname=KV datavalue=761
```

Above statement is working fine,now,

If the data value contains any alphabet it gives error.

```
interface1,KEY=bytes_allocated,fieldname=KV datavalue=761A
```

Error i am getting is

```
Failed to write: {"error":"unable to parse 
'interface1,KEY=bytes_allocated,fieldname=KV datavalue=761A': invalid number"}
```

Wondering how can i write "761A" into DB? or force influxDB to consider 761A as string value instead of number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a field value to be treated as a string, it must be wrapped in `"`s.

For example

```
interface1,KEY=bytes_allocated,fieldname=KV datavalue="761A"
```